# Is the order of sequences preserved in the limit in general Polish space?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that X is a Polish space with a natural order topology, that is, for any $x \in X$, both sets $\{ y: y \ge x\}$ and $\{y: y \le x\}$ are closed. Consider two sequences $x^n$ and $y^n$ in $X$, which converge to $x$ and $y$, respectively. If $x^n \ge y^n$ for all $n$, then $x \ge y$. The proof of this result is easy if $X$ is the Euclidean space but seems quite elusive in the general (Polish) space. I would much appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me with a proof.

Comment: By order you mean partial order?

Comment: Yes, it is a partially ordered space.

Comment: How does the proof for $X$ Euclidean work?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a boring counterexample: let $X = \mathbb{R}$ be equipped with its usual topology but a different partial order $\leq$ defined by,

$$a \leq b \Leftrightarrow a = b \, \mathrm{or} \, a = -r, b = r \, \mathrm{for \, some} \, r > 1$$

Then for any $x \in X$, both $\{y: y \geq x\}$ and $\{y: y \leq x\}$ are closed because both are finite. We have $-1-\frac{1}{n} \leq 1+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, but $\lim_n (-1-\frac{1}{n}) = -1 \not\leq 1 = \lim_n (1+\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Now, of course, if your condition had been $\{(x, y): x \leq y\} \subset X \times X$ is closed, then the result is obviously true. In fact, what you asked is just equivalent to that.

Comment: Thank you for a great counterexample! I thought that it would hold generally. In fact, the property does not need to hold even in the Euclidean space. Many thanks!